# jQuery Bootgrid replace tr no-results before charge content ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I have created a jQuery Bootgrid table connected with ajax content, and while loading ajax content, it shows me "No results Found!"

```
<td colspan="4" class="no-results">No results found!</td>
```

How can I change that td content, and put an image as the content is loading?

Answer (score 1):

Bootgrid provides a `labels` option you can use to override some texts. One of them is exactly what you want:

```
var grid = $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    url: "/api/data/basic",
    labels: {
        noResults: '<img src="http://www.example.com/not-found.png" />'
    }
});
```

In [their documentation](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#labels) you can check what other labels you can override. In your case, instead of replacing with other text, I replaced with an `img` html tag.

Look [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jzf42gf/) I created. Try searching for something that will result in "**no results found**".